# jQuery XML object to string

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I have a XML object in jQuery:

```
var xml_srt = ^xml string^;    
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml_string );
xml = $( xmlDoc );
```

It is working fine, but I don't know how I can make a string from this object.

If I use `console.log(xml);`, then it is fine. But I need a string.

Comment: If it helps, you could try $(xml) to turn it into a jQuery object

Comment: What string did you mean? Create a new xml element, read a element or change the value of an element? Greetz

Comment: I need all xml string ex: <rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>

Answer (score 0):

Use this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="someElement"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>



<script>
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );

/* append "RSS Title" to #someElement */
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );

/* change the title to "XML Title" */
$title.text( "XML Title" );

/* append "XML Title" to #anotherElement */
$( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

for more information : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: It is show, but just text. I need Full xml string: like->  <rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>